# Practice for inheritance

Tags: java, overriding

This is a practice question from my textbook.
It prints:

> Person
>
> Person

I'm wondering why it won't print Person and then Student. Shouldn't getInfo be overrided for the Student instance, and print Student? I must be misunderstanding override.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Person().printPerson();
    new Student().printPerson();
  }
}

class Student extends Person {
  private String getInfo() {
    return "Student";
  }
}

class Person {
  private String getInfo() {
    return "Person";
  }
  
  public void printPerson() {
    System.out.println(getInfo());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have provided,the function `getinfo()` will not be over-ridden because you have declared the function as `private`.
A `private` function or variable is accessible or visible only in that particular class.

As a result,when `getinfo()` is called inside the superclass,it goes to it's own `getinfo()`
and not student's `getinfo()`.

In this case,even if the function was not private,it would not have called student's `getinfo()` because you are not using the student object to call it.You are simply calling the function.

What could you do?

- Replace `private` with `protected`.
  This would keep the function a bit secretive and will also make it available among the heirarchy members.

and then a small change:

```
System.out.println(this.getinfo());
```